# opencv sift - VS2015 debug assertion failed

Tags: c++, opencv, sift

I am trying to run a small and simple program using opencv in VS2015. The code is the following:

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>
#include<string>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main() {

Mat input1=imread("d_1.jpg", 0);
Mat input2 = imread("d_2.jpg", 0);
SiftFeatureDetector detector1,detector2;


vector<KeyPoint> keypoints1,keypoints2;
detector1.detect(input1, keypoints1);
/*detector2.detect(input2, keypoints2);

vector<DMatch> matches1to2;
Mat output1,output2,output;
drawKeypoints(input1, keypoints1, output1);

drawKeypoints(input2, keypoints2, output2);

drawMatches(input1,keypoints1,input2,keypoints2,matches1to2,output);
imwrite("first.jpg", output1);
imwrite("second.jpg", output2);
*/
return 0;
```

}

I get a Debug Assertion failed Error and the expression mentioned is "reinterpret_cast(_ptr_ptr)[-1]==_BIG_ALLOCATION_SENTINEL"&&0 and the file mentioned is Microsoft visual studio14\vc\include\xmemory0 Line:110.

I looked up other solutions here such as updating the platform to 2010 and checking the configuration to ensure all the included lib files belong to the correct VC version. That just ended up giving me more errors. So I reverted to the original config and ran this code line by line to see which line has the issue cos other wise, the program ran completely, gave output and the error was being reported after the return statement.
The error pops up after the detector.detect statement, I am not sure what the problem is. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: post your linker command please

Comment: Thanks for the reply! What exactly is a linker command? If you mean the options under the linker tab in the property pages of this program, I have Additional Library Directories set to $(OPENCV_LIB) (which evaluates to build\x64\vc12\lib) and I have multiple *d.lib files added as additional depenencies.

Comment: vc12 libs are for visual studio 2013. You have to find libs for visual studio 2015 or compile them yourself.

Comment: I will try that and get back, thank you!

Comment: That solved my issue, thanks again!